# Which postulate of GR requires that $ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}(x)dx^\mu dx^\nu$ must be invariant?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, symmetry, covariance

The postulate that the velocity of light in a vacuum is the same in all inertial frames, can be exploited to establish that the *spacetime interval* between two events $x^\mu=(ct,{\bf r})$ and $x^\mu+dx^\mu=(ct+cdt,{\bf r}+d{\bf r})$ defined as $$ds^2=\eta_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu=c^2dt^2-d{\bf r}^2\tag{1}$$ remains invariant.

In general relativity, we require $$ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}(x)dx^\mu dx^\nu \tag{2}$$ to be invariant. Which postulate of general relativity gives rise to this requirement?

Comment: This is not a postulate, this is $g_{\mu \nu}$ _definition_.

Comment: In SR we work with Lorentz transformations, under which the line element (1) is manifestly invariant. In GR we work with general coordinate transformations, under which (2), which is just the metric tensor ($g_{ab}(x)$ are the components), is manifestly invariant.